# How to change localhost to MongoDb and Heroku host

Tags: mongodb, react-native, heroku, localhost, expo

so i finish to build my app with mongodb express react native with expo ,
and im trying to change the local host server with port 3000, to real host server with horuko and mongodb.

- i was build and connected the mongoDb to heroku like the docs, i go to settings in heroku and paste the momngodb_uri , something like :

  ```
      mongodb+srv://admin:admin@lior.rva16.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
  ```
- in my Index server.js i change from local to :

  ```
  const port = process.env.PORT;// here i dont really have port (i dont know what to put inside)
    mongoose
     .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {///this line is - 
    >mongodb+srv://admin:admin@lior.rva16.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  ```

this is my env file:

```
   MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://admin:admin@lior.rva16.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
   JWT_SECRET=LKDSLCX9IOZiJS9IAJ768
```

1. in my client side all the request url is like:

   ```
    await indexApi.post("/signout");
   ```
2. and until now i used with NGROK to connect and check my db so the base url until now is been:

   ```
     export default axios.create({
      baseURL: "http://cca1237fb2de.ngrok.io", //ngrok http 3000
      });
   ```

**the problem:**
i get errors that all of the is show that is cant connect to the url, he dont find the server url.
(note that with the localhost everything worked correctly)

**the question**:

1. how can i connect my app to heroku server
2. what is my new BaseUrl ? (im tried to do {process.env.MongoDB_Uri} but is also crash...)
3. the big question is "how can i replace the server from local to real server in heroku with mongo"

lin https://github.com/roeigr7/LIOR

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have an environment variable that stores your production/staging MONGO_URL. On your local machine you can use `dotenv` package to pull values from `.env` files and the environment variables you set on your heroku app deployment.

Local .env

```
MONGO_URL=mymongourl
```

You can set environment variables in your heroku app by going to Settings > Config Vars. There should be a button named `Reveal Config Vars`. Click on that and it will give you an interface to add more environment variables.

Code

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

...other code

const mongoURL = process.env.MONGO_URL
```

Comment: its exactlly wha i have... but its not succeed to connect,he dont find it...he failed with Error: Request failed with status code 404]

Comment: You should have the `.env` file in your gitignore file. That should never be committed. You should also never reveal your env variables in a stackoverflow post or a in your repo. Move the procfile to the root of your repo and make your root package.json have the script `cd server && node index.js`. Change your procfile's web command to npm run start and that should solve your problem. I think what is happening is that your server doesn't even start because heroku doesn't go into server dir and run it. You should also use heroku's cli to diagnose problems.